# Error in the Snakefile when running tutorial

Tags: snakemake, pypsa

When I try to follow the tutorial from Pypsa's site "https://pypsa-eur.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html" I get an error when I try to do a dry-run for the optimization. I will say that I couldn't find the config.tutorial.yaml file, so I am using the default.config.yaml that comes with the Pypsa-Eur repository from GitHub.

$ snakemake -j 1 -n results/networks/elec_s_6_ec_lcopt_Co2L-24H.nc

IndentationError in file C:\Users\augusts\Documents\PyPSA\pypsa-eur\Snakefile, line 59:
expected an indented block after 'if' statement on line 81:
script:

has anyone else experienced something like this? Or is there any obvious errors in the way I am performing the operation? I am trying to get into the use of Pypsa, but I find it hard to find good, up to date, content that tells me how to acctually use it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not following at all why you say, "I will say that I couldn't find the config.tutorial.yaml file"? It is found where it is described [there at the top of the tutorial](https://pypsa-eur.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) at [`config/test/config.electricity.yaml`](https://github.com/PyPSA/pypsa-eur/blob/master/config/test/config.electricity.yaml). This is covered in [an update from a year ago](https://pypsa-eur.readthedocs.io/en/latest/release_notes.html#pypsa-eur-0-8-0-18th-march-2023):  "Deleted config.tutorial.yaml, which is superseded by test/config.electricity.yaml." That ...

Comment: <continued> Is there a part of the tutorial that is referencing old code? Or part o the config file? Please point to where this is, if so. On a different subject (although maybe not since I cannot relate what you say to the tutorial).... Please describe better how far into the tutorial you made it? "when I try to do a dry-run for the optimization". I'm not seeing an obvious correspondence to that part of [the 'Tutorial: Electricity-Only'l](https://pypsa-eur.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) that you link to? Can you make it clearer?

Comment: You are providing very little details as to what you have done to try and investigate/troubleshoot this? Maybe it is attributable all to not using the correct config file and so this ties back to why you aren't and then seeking help after starting off on the foot. Then you provide no details related to the error. What the situation on your actual system now? I see line 59 of `Snakefile`, [here](https://github.com/PyPSA/pypsa-eur/blob/d72576aa1a45a2061d0bc88818db8ca16874c468/Snakefile#L59), ...

Comment: <continued> as being `include: "rules/solve_overnight.smk"`. Is that what you have? What is line 81 referring to? [`rules/solve_overnight.smk"`](https://github.com/PyPSA/pypsa-eur/blob/master/rules/solve_overnight.smk) doesn't have more than 44 lines and so it cannot be that. And so more questions arise that you haven't addressed? We don't have access to your system and you haven't helped bring us along. This is probably why someone already voted to close this.